# What happens to pantheon-mail?

Tags: pantheon-mail

It will freeze for awhile if I try to reply the mail, and the page will become black if I click on it, it is almost unusable when it happens.

Here is the situation:
https://youtu.be/nyVBgHdSgEc

Comment: I am facing the same exact issue, but haven't found a solution. Perhaps you should edit the title to be more descriptive, so that this attracts more attention. I created a bug report for this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-mail/+bug/1630345